# Laravel check if artisan command is running which triggers an SSE

Tags: laravel, cron

I'm using a privately made SDK by some company where I have to get messages from using an SSE stream. Right now I run my function in my controller which sends a GET to the server and keeps the connection alive. I'm triggering this from my console. I've made a command `php artisan fetch:messages` which starts calls my controller method and starts the connection.

Right now, if I close my console the SSE stream also closes. How can I keep this alive when I'm away? Because this has to be active at all times.

I tried making a laravel schedule that triggers `php artisan fetch:messages` command every few minutes but I cannot see if the previous command is active or not.

Comment: You can use something like supervisor to keep your command running indefinitely. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: isn't Supervisor only for jobs?

Comment: No, supervisor is a process manager. You use it run your artisan command and it will restart the command if for some reason it dies/stops/exits.

Comment: I forgot to thank you. This solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help.